# css - dock one panel and scroll other panel

Tags: html, css

I have to place two panels next to each other.

[image]

The **left panel** has a **variable width** and it **fixed**.
The **right panel** should expand on the rest of the width and includes a scrollbar when necessary.

I tried this:

```css
.container {
  width:100%;
}
.scroll-panel {
  float:right;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap
  width:calc(100% - 250px - 5px);
}
.fixed-panel{
  width:250px;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="scroll-panel">...</div>
   <div class="fixed-panel">...</div>
</div>
```

It works well but in this case I write the width (250px) in css. I have to support an **auto width** in left panel.

I searched for a solution and did not find anything.
Anyone know a solution for such a case?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use flexbox, see this tutorial for more info https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display: flex` in the parent container to make both divs share the horizontal space and remove `float` for its children.

For the scroll panel add `flex-grow: 1` so it takes over all of the remaining space.

```
.container {
  width:100%;
  display: flex;
}

.scroll-panel {
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.fixed-panel{
}
```

Hope this works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Add to fixed panel:

```
 position: fixed;
 left: 0;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: sorry, but in this case, the fixed panel cover the scroll panel.